# Does aurora serverless cost money even if it is not used?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created a serverless aurora database and created a database and filled it. Without using it for reading and writing, i get priced for it.

Does the aurora serverless database costs money monthly even though i do not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only pay for **storage** if you are not using it. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.how-it-works.pause-resume):

> When the DB cluster is paused, no compute or memory activity occurs, and you **are charged only for storage**.

Comment: I forgot to configure the pause option, thank you

Comment: there is a least amount of time, that has to go by in order to accept, otherwise i would have done it earlier